# (0x80004005): Column length too big for column 'ModelHash'

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am using code first in EF 4.1 Update 1 with MySQL and the 6.4.3 .NET connector. I get the following exception:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Column length too
>   big for column 'ModelHash' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead

How do I tell EF to use Text instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the database type in the mapping:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntityType>().Property(e => e.ModelHash).HasColumnType("TEXT");
    }
}
```

Or with data annotations

```
public class YourEntityType
{
    [Column(TypeName = "TEXT")]
    public string ModelHash { get; set; }
}
```

But I have some suspicion that `ModelHash` is not your column, is it? It sounds like column from `EdmMetadata` table and in such case you probably cannot control it this way. That would be either bug in EF or in MySQL connector.

Comment: Yes it is not my column and is indeed from EdmMetaData. So I am still looking for a solution or a work around. I cannot believe I am the only EF/MySQL user with this problem. :-)